# Foundry exponential representation of a number not working in console.log

Tags: solidity

`console.log("number: %e", 555555);` should return `number: 5.55555e5` but it simply returns `number: e 555555`

I've tried by assigning it as a variable first, but it gives the same result:
`uint256 num = 555555;`
`console.log("number:", num);`

I've also tried using %x but that does the same only replaces "e" with "x". Update to latest version also done